# How to efficiently iterate over a pandas dataframe dynamically looking to its rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have thousands of csv files. Each file has something about 1k lines in the following structure

```
Hour  Val1 Val2
9:00  2    3
9:05  1    4
9:10  5    6 
9:15  4    8
9:20  6    4
```

What I need is: verify if `Val2` in row `x` is bigger then `Val1` in row `x-1` and row `x+1`

A basic output for this problem is:

```
Hour Cond
9:00 False
9:05 False
9:10 True
9:15 True
9:20 False
```

Of course I know that I can do this using a for loop, but I dont know if is the most optimized way. Searching in other Stack OverFlow references, I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas) and the author of the second answer says **e*xplicitly to not iterate over a pandas DF***.

So, finally, my doubts are:

**1. Considering the answer of the reference post, is there a way to solve this problem without iterating on dataframes rows?**

**2. Is pandas the best approach to do this?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterate the list of dfs and compute cond as follows. dont iterate the df rows please. Its the anticlimax

```
df =df.assign(cond=(df['Val2'].gt(df['Val1'].shift()))&(df['Val2'].gt(df['Val1'].shift(-1))))
```